# Проблема с Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-events, vue-router

Ввсем привет, столкнулася с казалось бы триавиальной задачей - подключить `smooth mouse wheel scroll`. Ранее писал на `jquery` и  это было  довольно просто.
Но вот с `native js\Vue` у меня пока что мало опыта. Буду благодарен за любой совет

[Вот скрипт](https://gist.github.com/SamJakob/c9175a4c2440e1b14b0b8cf7d99d2d24#file-smoothscroll-js) который я использовал на своем сайте.

Проблема в том, что для навигации между страницами я использую **router-link** , и из-за этого скрипт работает неправильно. Мне  нужно что бы  при переходе  на другую страницу  `scroll position` всегда  была в самом верху.

Думаю, что его инициализировать какждый разй при переходе на новую страницу.
Буду благодарен за дельный совет

вот код:

```
function SmoothScroll(target, speed, smooth) {
  let targetEl = target;
  if (targetEl === document) {
    targetEl = (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body);
  } // cross browser support for document scrolling

  let moving = false;
  let pos = targetEl.scrollTop;

  const requestFrame = (function () { // requestAnimationFrame cross browser
    return (
      window.requestAnimationFrame
      || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
      || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
      || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
      || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
      || function (func) {
        window.setTimeout(func, 1000 / 50);
      }
    );
  }());

  function update() {
    moving = true;
    let delta = (pos - targetEl.scrollTop) / smooth;

    delta -= 1;

    if (pos - targetEl.scrollTop === smooth) delta = 0;

    targetEl.scrollTop += delta;
    if (Math.abs(delta) > 0.5) requestFrame(update);
    else moving = false;
  }


  function scrolled(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // disable default scrolling

    let delta = e.delta || e.wheelDelta;
    if (delta === undefined) {
      // we are on firefox
      delta = -e.detail;
    }
    delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, delta));

    pos += -delta * speed;
    pos = Math.max(0, Math.min(pos, targetEl.scrollHeight - targetEl.clientHeight)); // limit scrolling

    if (!moving) update();
  }
  target.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrolled, { passive: false });
  target.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scrolled, { passive: false });
}
function init() {
  window.smoothScroll = new SmoothScroll(document, 120, 12);
}

init();
```

Comment: Вы не можите либу подключить?

Comment: @doox911 я ее подключил, проблема в том, что она не совсем приавльно работает

Comment: В чём это проявляется и как вы её подключили?

Comment: @doox911 подключал в mounted() в корневом  шаблоне проекта - app.vue

Грешу  на то, что  неправильно отрабытывает скрипт, т.к. у всех страниц scrollHeight  разная, потому калькулирует неправильно и появляются поддергивания страница загружается не в том месте ( ) и тп.
Думаю, что если скрипт инициализировать каждый раз при переходе  на страницу - это может.
Вопрос в том как это следать с помощью vue-router ?

Comment: Модуль должен быть подключён в объект `window`. Так же приложите ссылку на пакет(модуль).